# create new array by cutting key from an existing array over to the new array

Tags: php

i want to take an array and cut some of the keys from it (not in order) and create a new array from them.

I have doing it using the `array_shift()` function, but came to a point where the next key needed to be skipped and then do the array_shift again.

How can I logically tackle this?

my array

```
Array
(
    [api] => Array
        (
            [0] => system
            [1] => assets
            [2] => theme
            [3] => resources
            [4] => api
            [5] => xml
            [6] => json
            [7] => jsonp
            [8] => request
        )

    [class] => Array
        (
            [name] => authentication
            [abbr] => auth
        )

    [directories] => Array
        (
            [application] => application
            [mvc] => Array
                (
                    [model] => model
                    [view] => view
                    [controller] => controller
                )

            [assets] => Array
                (
                    [folder] => assets
                    [css] => css
                    [img] => img
                    [js] => js
                )

            [config] => config
        )

    [smarty] => Array
        (
            [security] => on
            [delimiter] => Array
                (
                    [left] => {!
                    [right] => !}
                )

            [template] => Array
                (
                    [header] => header
                    [footer] => footer
                    [extension] => tpl
                )

        )

    [version] => Array
        (
            [component] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => CMS
                            [version] => 1.0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => TinyMCE jQuery Package
                            [version] => 3.5
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => jQuery
                            [version] => 1.7.2
                        )

                )

            )
)
```

I need to make a new array from they keys: `api`, `class`, `version`

Comment: Can you give us an example. Is there a definable criteria that determines which elements you're taking, and which ones you're leaving?

Comment: Post some concrete examples / parts of your code, this will help us provide a meaningful solution.

Comment: What do you want to copy from the mentioned array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an explicit list of keys that you'd like to move from one array to another. Cycle over that list, pulling from one and adding to another. Then remove the old copy from the original array:

```
// Original Array, and empty Array
$array = array( 'api' => 1, 'class' => 2, 'fizz' => 3, 'buzz' => 4 );
$newAr = array();

// For each key we'd like to keep
foreach ( array( 'api', 'class' ) as $key ) {
  // (Re)move the value from the original array to our new array
  $newAr[$key] = $array[$key]; unset( $array[$key] );
}

// Show the contents of the new array
print_r( $newAr );
```

Try it online now: http://codepad.org/7iYG4iVB

Answer (score 1):

If it's just those 3 keys you need:

```
$newArray = array(
    "api" => $oldArray["api"],
    "class" => $oldArray["class"],
    "version" => $oldArray["version"]
);
```

Comment: but i need to cut then out of the existing array

Comment: `$oldArray` would be your existing array. `$newArray` would contain only those 3 keys and the contents of the old array.

Comment: I don't know who's downvoting and not defending their vote, but they downvoted the correct answers. So have an upvote. Clearly this answer is better than looping over the array, as it runs in constant time, as opposed to O(n).

Comment: I didn't downvote, however this solution leaves the values within the original array. If I'm not mistaken, the OP wanted them removed from the original array.

Comment: You can always overwrite the original with the new afterwards... (I know you probably know that, just saying)

Comment: @ccKep I think the OP was wanting some direction there.

Answer (score 0):

There's [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice) which lets you 'slice' out a portion of an array. That portion can be a single element, or a range of elements. Basically the slice function lets you hack 'n chop on an array like substr() lets you hack 'n chop up a string.

Comment: seems to be close to what i want, i just don't understand the logic on  how to go about using the `array_splice`

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = array(1, 5, 'foo');

$new = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $new[$key] = $old[$key];
    // or maybe just $new[] = $old[$key];
    unset($old[$key]);
}
```

There's shorter ways to do this, but I think you can understand how this works.

edit - Here's a shorter way

```
$keys = array(1, 5);
$new = array_intersect_key($old, array_flip($keys)));
$old = array_diff_key($old, array_flip($keys)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems too simple:

```
$new_array = array( 
    'api' => $old_array['api'],
    'class' => $old_array['class'],
    'version' => $old_array['version']
);
```

Then do a `var_dump( $new_array);` to see if it contains the desired output.